# Debug C by gdb shows information about inline function is different

Tags: c, gdb, vscode-debugger, gdbserver

I debug for a C program by gdb. When stepping in a normal function, the command "info stack" will show information about that function and the main function information (where the normal function is called). But when stepping in an inline function, the command "info stack" only shows the information about the inline function. Is this a feature or limited of the gdb?

I expected that the command "info stack" will show full information when stepping an inline function

Comment: please add a [mre] and a screenshot and textual description of what exactly you see.